# Which theme template is used renders next page

Tags: themes

I am building a theme from scratch to be used here. http://www.bel-viso.co.uk/gemma-permanent-makeup-blog/ . This page lists all the recent posts and breaks them off after every 5. 
If you click on the next page however, it doesn't render correctly see: http://www.bel-viso.co.uk/gemma-permanent-makeup-blog/page/2

Please can you tell me which template file I need to provide to get this sorted? 
Thanks

Comment: It would be helpful to know **what template files you *currently* have**, and also to see the relevant code. This issue is more likely a posts-per-page pagination issue rather than a template issue.

Answer (score 1):

A `paged.php` template file should do the job.

[image]

Comment: Note: `paged.php` is invoked only if `archive.php` and any of its subordinate template files do not exist.