# How to find out which template the HTML content comes from?

Tags: themes, templates

At [my page](http://md4s1307.keaweb.dk/shop/page/3/), I want to change the text "next" and "previous" at the bottom of the page, but I can't figure out which PHP template it derives from. I tried searching the classes that was connected to the object, but without luck. Is there any developer tool or plugin, that could be of any help?

Comment: Check [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/97744/determine-which-template-slug-php-is-being-loaded) and [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/52192/which-theme-template-is-used-renders-next-page).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the plugin [Debug Objects](https://github.com/bueltge/Debug-Objects), this have a option to get outside the templates, folder, file etc. and much more.  Makes easier to debug a installed site.